# Build chain in the cloud?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, shippable-ci

(I understand this question is somewhat out of scope for stack overflow, because contains more problems and somewhat vague. Suggestions to ask it in the proper ways are welcome.)

I have some open source projects depending in each other.
The code resides in github, the builds happen in shippable, using docker images which in turn are built on docker hub.
I have set up an artifact repo and a debian repository where shippable builds put the packages, and docker builds use them.
The build chain looks like this in terms of deliverables:

1. pre-zenta docker image
2. zenta docker image (two steps of docker build because it would time out otherwise)
3. zenta debian package
4. zenta-tools docker image
5. zenta-tools debian package
6. xslt docker image
7. adadocs artifacts

Currently I am triggering the builds by pushing to github and sometimes rerunning failed builds on shippable after the docker build ran.

I am looking for solutions for the following problems:

1. Where to put Dockerfiles? Now they are in the repo of the package needing the resulting docker image for build. This way all information to build the package are in one place, but sometimes I have to trigger an extra build to have the package actually built.
2. How to trigger build automatically?
3. ..., in a way supporting git-flow? For example if I change the code in zenta develop branch, I want to make sure that zenta-tools will build and test with the development version of it, before merging with master.
4. Are there a tool with which I can overview the health of the whole build chain?

Comment: you might be interested in following the Devops site proposal,  intended exactly for such questions considered off-topic on other SE sites: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops?referrer=cZS_mCq3NdL7h376hrOevQ2

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is related to [Shippable](https://app.shippable.com), I've created a support issue for you here - https://github.com/Shippable/support/issues/2662. If you are interested in discussing the best way to handle your scenario, you can also send me an email at support@shippable.com You can set up your entire flow, including building the docker images, using Shippable.

Comment: Upped for great support.